# Errors happened When I Build jSS7 with maven

Tags: maven, restcomm

Recently I face a problem when I build JSS7 with sources on kali. Every step goes well, but in the final step when I run the command:
`mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`, I get this error tip:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.080 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-02T05:57:49-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/kali/.m2). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

I tried to search but seems my case is not applicable to those solutions. Can anyone give me a hand, please? Thank you

UPDATED:
So another error happened when the building was continuing. I got tips like these:-

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Inspecting build with total of 81 modules...
[INFO] Not installing Nexus Staging features:
[INFO]  * Preexisting staging related goal bindings found in 81 modules.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] RestComm jSS7 :: ss7-parent                                        [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Scheduler :: scheduler                            [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Congestion :: congestion                          [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistics :: Parent :: statistics-parent         [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistics :: Api :: statistics-api               [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistics :: Impl :: statistics-impl             [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: management                                        [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management :: shell-transport                     [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management :: shell-client                        [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management :: shell-server-api                    [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management :: shell-server-impl                   [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MTP :: Parent :: mtp-parent                       [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MTP :: Impl :: mtp-api                            [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MTP :: Impl :: mtp                                [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: Parent :: m3ua                            [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: Api :: m3ua-api                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: Impl :: m3ua-impl                         [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: CLI :: m3ua-cli-sctp                      [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: CLI :: m3ua-cli-m3ua                      [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: Parent :: restcomm-hardware           [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: linkset                               [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: linkset-cli                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: restcomm-dahdi-parent                 [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: restcomm-dahdi-native                 [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: restcomm-dahdi                        [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: restcomm-dialogic-parent              [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: restcomm-dialogic                     [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: ISUP :: Parent :: isup-parent                     [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: ISUP :: Api :: isup-api                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: ISUP :: Impl :: isup-impl                         [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SCCP :: Parent :: sccp-parent                     [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SCCP :: Api :: sccp-api                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SCCP :: Impl :: sccp-impl                         [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SCCP :: CLI :: sccp-cli                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP :: Parent :: tcap-parent                     [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP :: Api :: tcap-api                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP :: Impl :: tcap-impl                         [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP :: CLI :: tcap-cli                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP-ANSI :: Parent :: tcap-ansi-parent           [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP ANSI :: Api :: tcap-ansi-api                 [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP ANSI :: Impl :: tcap-ansi-impl               [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP-ANSI :: CLI :: tcap-ansi-cli                 [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MAP :: Parent :: map-parent                       [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MAP :: Api :: map-api                             [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MAP :: Impl :: map-impl                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MAP :: LOAD :: map-load                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: INAP :: Parent :: inap-parent                     [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: INAP :: Api :: inap-api                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: INAP :: Impl :: inap-impl                         [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: CAP :: Parent :: cap-parent                       [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: CAP :: Api :: cap-api                             [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: CAP :: Impl :: cap-impl                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: restcomm-ss7-oam                                  [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: restcomm-ss7-oam-common                           [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: jmx                             [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: alarm                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistic-oam :: Parent :: statistics-oam-parent  [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistic-oam :: API :: statistics-oam-api        [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistic-oam :: Impl :: statistics-oam-impl      [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx-ss7 :: jmxss7                      [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-sctp-oam :: sctp-oam                   [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: m3ua-oam                        [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: sccp-oam                        [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: tcap-oam                        [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: map-oam                         [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: linkset-oam                     [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management :: UI :: new-ui                        [war]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: restcomm-ss7                                      [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SGW :: Parent :: restcomm-sgw                     [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SGW :: Gateway :: gateway                         [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SGW :: Boot :: boot                               [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Tools :: Parent                                   [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simulator :: Parent                                  [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simulator :: Simulator core                          [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simulator :: Simulator GUI                           [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simulator :: Simulator Bootstrap                     [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Trase Parser :: Parent                               [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Trase Parser :: Trase Parser core                    [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Trase Parser :: Trase Parser Bootstrap               [jar]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simple alarm listener :: Parent                      [pom]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simple alarm listener :: SimpleAlarmListener-core    [jar]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< org.mobicents.protocols.ss7:ss7-parent >---------------
[INFO] Building RestComm jSS7 :: ss7-parent 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT               [1/81]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ ss7-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.9.1:checkstyle (check-style) @ ss7-parent ---                                                                        
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.4:manifest (bundle-manifest) @ ss7-parent ---
[WARNING] Ignoring project type pom - supportedProjectTypes = [jar, bundle, war]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ ss7-parent ---
[INFO] Installing /home/kali/jss7-attack-simulator/pom.xml to /home/kali/.m2/repository/org/mobicents/protocols/ss7/ss7-parent/7.0.0-SNAPSHOT/ss7-parent-7.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------< org.mobicents.protocols.ss7.scheduler:scheduler >-----------
[INFO] Building Restcomm jSS7 :: Scheduler :: scheduler 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT   [2/81]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ scheduler ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/kali/jss7-attack-simulator/scheduler/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ scheduler ---                                                                       
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/kali/jss7-attack-simulator/scheduler/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ scheduler ---
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /home/kali/jss7-attack-simulator/scheduler/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for RestComm jSS7 :: ss7-parent 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] RestComm jSS7 :: ss7-parent ........................ SUCCESS [  0.774 s]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Scheduler :: scheduler ............ FAILURE [  0.287 s]
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Congestion :: congestion .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistics :: Parent :: statistics-parent SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistics :: Api :: statistics-api SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistics :: Impl :: statistics-impl SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: management ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management :: shell-transport ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management :: shell-client ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management :: shell-server-api .... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management :: shell-server-impl ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MTP :: Parent :: mtp-parent ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MTP :: Impl :: mtp-api ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MTP :: Impl :: mtp ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: Parent :: m3ua ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: Api :: m3ua-api ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: Impl :: m3ua-impl ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: CLI :: m3ua-cli-sctp ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: M3UA :: CLI :: m3ua-cli-m3ua ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: Parent :: restcomm-hardware SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: linkset ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: linkset-cli ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: restcomm-dahdi-parent . SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: restcomm-dahdi-native . SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: restcomm-dahdi ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: restcomm-dialogic-parent SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Hardware :: restcomm-dialogic ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: ISUP :: Parent :: isup-parent ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: ISUP :: Api :: isup-api ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: ISUP :: Impl :: isup-impl ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SCCP :: Parent :: sccp-parent ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SCCP :: Api :: sccp-api ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SCCP :: Impl :: sccp-impl ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SCCP :: CLI :: sccp-cli ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP :: Parent :: tcap-parent ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP :: Api :: tcap-api ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP :: Impl :: tcap-impl ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP :: CLI :: tcap-cli ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP-ANSI :: Parent :: tcap-ansi-parent SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP ANSI :: Api :: tcap-ansi-api . SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP ANSI :: Impl :: tcap-ansi-impl SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: TCAP-ANSI :: CLI :: tcap-ansi-cli . SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MAP :: Parent :: map-parent ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MAP :: Api :: map-api ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MAP :: Impl :: map-impl ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: MAP :: LOAD :: map-load ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: INAP :: Parent :: inap-parent ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: INAP :: Api :: inap-api ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: INAP :: Impl :: inap-impl ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: CAP :: Parent :: cap-parent ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: CAP :: Api :: cap-api ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: CAP :: Impl :: cap-impl ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: restcomm-ss7-oam .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: restcomm-ss7-oam-common ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: jmx ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: alarm ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistic-oam :: Parent :: statistics-oam-parent SKIPPED                                                                          
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistic-oam :: API :: statistics-oam-api SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Statistic-oam :: Impl :: statistics-oam-impl SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx-ss7 :: jmxss7 ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-sctp-oam :: sctp-oam ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: m3ua-oam ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: sccp-oam ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: tcap-oam ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: map-oam ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management-jmx :: linkset-oam ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Management :: UI :: new-ui ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: restcomm-ss7 ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SGW :: Parent :: restcomm-sgw ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SGW :: Gateway :: gateway ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: SGW :: Boot :: boot ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 :: Tools :: Parent ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simulator :: Parent .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simulator :: Simulator core .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simulator :: Simulator GUI ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simulator :: Simulator Bootstrap ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Trase Parser :: Parent ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Trase Parser :: Trase Parser core .... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Trase Parser :: Trase Parser Bootstrap SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simple alarm listener :: Parent ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Restcomm jSS7 Simple alarm listener :: SimpleAlarmListener-core SKIPPED                                                                            
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.465 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-02-02T07:09:57-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project scheduler: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] error: Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
[ERROR] error: Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :scheduler
```

Seems something went wrong about "scheduler". Can anyone help me how to resolve them? Thanks.

Comment: Please check the error message: `Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. `

Comment: @khmarbaise Hello. Thank you, I found that is because I have no pom
 firstly. The building is continuing.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).